# MySQL pivot to make a row into a colum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I have three tables, `products`, `customers`, `order`

Product:

```
id | name |
 1 | milk |
 2 | bread|
 3 | Pea  |
```

Customer:

```
id | name  | category
1  | James | retailer
2  | Paul  | vendor
3  | Dave  | retailer
```

Order:

```
id  | product_id | customer_id | qty | price
 1  | 1          | 2           | 23  | 50 
 2  | 2          | 2           | 4   | 30
 3  | 3          | 2           | 6   | 10
 4  | 2          | 1           | 9   | 30
 5  | 3          | 1           | 2   | 10
 6  | 1          | 3           | 6   | 50
 7  | 3          | 3           | 7   | 10
```

When i do a query to show transactions by customers with category of `vendor` like

```sql
SELECT customer.name, product.name as pname, order.qty, order.price FROM customer, product, order 
WHERE customer.id = order.customer_id 
AND product.id = order.product_id AND customer.category = "vendor"
```

i will get something like:

```
name |  pname | qty | price
Paul |  milk  | 23  | 50
Paul |  bread | 4   | 30
Paul |  pea   | 6   | 10
```

I want this instead:

```
name | milk  | bread  | pea  | total
Paul | 23    | 4      | 6    | 90
```

While that of retailers will look like this:

```sql
SELECT customer.name, product.name as pname, order.qty, order.price FROM 
customer, product, order 
WHERE customer.id = order.customer_id 
AND product.id = order.product_id AND customer.category = "retailer"
```

I will get a table like this:

```
 name |  pname | qty | price
James |  bread | 9   | 30
James |  pea   | 2   | 10
 Dave |  milk  | 6   | 50
 Dave |  pea   | 7   | 10
```

But i want this instead:

```
name  | milk  | bread  | pea  | total
James | 0     |  9     | 2    | 40
Dave  | 6     |  0     | 7    | 60
```

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use conditional aggregation for pivoting columns. And be sure to use explicit joins instead of the deprecated implicit join as former has been the standard for 25 years in ANSI-92.

```sql
SELECT c.name,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.name = 'milk' THEN o.qty ELSE 0 END) as milk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.name = 'bread' THEN o.qty ELSE 0 END) as bread,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.name = 'pea' THEN o.qty ELSE 0 END) as pea,
       SUM(o.price) AS Total 
FROM `customer` c
INNER JOIN `order` o
  ON c.id = o.customer_id 
INNER JOIN `product` p
  ON p.id = o.product_id 
WHERE c.category = 'vendor'   -- same for retailer
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: awesome! just what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot have this response structure directly from one simple select

```
name  | milk  | bread  | pea  | total
James | 0     |  9     | 2    | 40
Dave  | 6     |  0     | 7    | 60
```

because your database is getting one row foreach retailers/customer order.

I know that using a server language like PHP or Java you will can handle the data and retrive like you want.